# JavaScript if statement ignores condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement, materialize

I'm have a JavaScript code to validate my contact form and do the POST to PHP script, the problem is that script ignors the IF statement and do the post while the response from my validateForm function is false.

If validateForm() returns false, it's still doing the POST action

Here's a print of console with the result of the function

[image: Result]

My JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name='contactf']").submit(function(e) {             
        // do the extra stuff here      
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(validateForm());
        if(validateForm()){                     
            $.ajax({                
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),            
                success: function(data) {                   
                    if(data.message == 'success'){                      
                        M.toast({html: 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!'})
                        $('#first_name').val('');
                        $('#last_name').val('');
                        $('#subject').val('');
                        $('#email').val('');
                        $('#phone').val('');
                        $('#details').val('');
                    }else if(data.message == 'error'){
                        M.toast({html: 'Ops... Tente novamente dentro de alguns minutos.'})
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else
            ;
    })
    function validateForm()
    {
        var name=document.forms["contactf"]["first_name"].value;
        var surname=document.forms["contactf"]["last_name"].value;
        var subject=document.forms["contactf"]["subject"].value;
        var mail=document.forms["contactf"]["email"].value;
        var phone=document.forms["contactf"]["phone"].value;
        var details=document.forms["contactf"]["details"].value;
        var isnum = /^\d+$/.test(phone);        
        if(!isnum){
            M.toast({html: 'O telefone deve conter apenas números!'});
            return false;
        }       
        else if (!name || !surname || !subject || !mail || !phone || !details)
        {
            M.toast({html: 'Preencha todos os campos!'})
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;        
    }   
    function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you be completely sure your validateForm function is not returning true?

Comment: have you debugged it? if you step through the function it should be fairly clear what is happening.  As said above your IF logic looks weird...

Comment: Wait - that `else if` in `validateForm()` is wrong. You've separated expressions with commas, and I doubt that's what you really want. The comma won't do what you think.

Comment: I have never seen this syntax (using commas) before: `if (name==null || name=="",surname==null || ...`

Comment: The comma operator `,` should probably be another logical OR `||` otherwise you're only testing `details`

Comment: I replaced the comma operator `,` by `||` and it's still not working. I had printed the result of `validateForm()`, and even false, the code proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boolean logic is wrong.

Instead you can use **`!value`** which produces `true` if **`value`** is null or an empty string, and then **OR** all of them using `||`.

This is based on type coercion into Boolean values, for more on this see e.g. [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Example:

```js
function validateForm(v1, v2, v3) {
  var name = v1;
  var surname = v2;
  var subject = v3;

  if (!name || !surname || !subject)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

console.log(validateForm(null, null, null));
console.log(validateForm(null, "", "Test"));
console.log(validateForm("John", "Smith", "Test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `else if` condition. 
Write the condition like:

```
else if (name==null || name=="" || surname==null || surname=="" || subject==null || subject=="" || mail==null || mail=="" || phone==null || phone=="" || details==null || details=="")
```

Don't use **Comma (,)** for separation.

Comment: why this may work, Peter B.'s solution is far more elegant

Comment: Check this [Try removing **name** value]
https://jsfiddle.net/7dhgo8ca/

Comment: and I agree about Peter B.'s way. All I wanted to say, Murilo Pereira can make his code work by just removing those **(,)** inside the condition.

Comment: @DelowarHossain thanks for the jsfiddle, there the codes works, I had made the changes and without success, maybe this can  be an Ajax bug?

Comment: You have an empty **else** after **if(validateForm())**, try fixing that. It may help.

Comment: With or without the empty else, the problem keeps

Comment: There's also another empty **else** in the bottom side. And use google chrome dev tools to see whether it generates any error.